# How to do multiple counts / exists in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to figure out how I can check for two things from one table without making two calls to mysql.

I have a `Members` table. I'd like to test whether a certain value exists in the `MemberID` column, and whether a certain value exists in the `PhoneNumber` column. `MemberID` and `PhoneNumber` are both indexed.

But there's something wrong with the syntax I'm trying. For example, each of

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS IDExists FROM Members WHERE MemberID = '999999999999' LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS PhoneExists FROM Members WHERE PhoneNumber = '5555555555' LIMIT 1
```

works. Why can't they be combined, somehow, like

```
SELECT (COUNT(1) AS IDExists FROM Members WHERE MemberID = '999999999999' LIMIT 1), (COUNT(1) AS PhoneExists FROM Members WHERE PhoneNumber = '5555555555' LIMIT 1)
```

?

Or perhaps, since I only care whether the value occurs zero times, or at all, something like

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Members WHERE MemberID = '999999999999')
```

?

But, unfortunately, there's something wrong with that syntax even for the case of one of my inquiries.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two working query like this:

```
select a.IDExists, b.PhoneExists
from (SELECT COUNT(1) AS IDExists FROM Members WHERE MemberID = '999999999999' LIMIT 1) a,
     (SELECT COUNT(1) AS PhoneExists FROM Members WHERE PhoneNumber = '5555555555' LIMIT 1) b
```

Though the query join two results with cartesian product, it is guaranteed that each result has only one row, it would not be a problem.

I'm not sure how big is the table and what kinds of index it has. If the table is big, then perhaps you have indexes on column `MemberID` and `PhoneNumber` respectively, then the above query will return the result quickly.

Comment: Yes, there are indexes on both `MemberID` and `PhoneNumber`. That's important in answering so I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You want a conditional `SUM`

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c706e/4)

```
SELECT 
    SUM( CASE 
             WHEN PhoneNumber = '5555555555' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
         END) PhoneExists,
    SUM( CASE 
             WHEN MemberID = '999999999999' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
         END) IDExists
FROM Members
```

Comment: @ntalbs `SUM` will only return a single row. I include a SqlFiddle in my answer and fix the syntaxis error.